# 405 Method: connection_mark_unattached_ap_()

Tags: configuration, firefox, proxy, https, web-proxy

```
Nov 12 18:46:07 [removed] Tor[15935]: Saying "HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed\r\n\r\n"
Nov 12 18:46:07 [removed] Tor[15935]: connection_mark_unattached_ap_(): Bug: stream (marked at ../src/or/connection_edge.c:2544) sending two socks replies? (on Tor 0.3.2.4-alpha )
Nov 12 18:46:07 [removed] Tor[15935]: Saying "HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed\r\n\r\n"
Nov 12 18:46:07 [removed] Tor[15935]: connection_mark_unattached_ap_(): Bug: stream (marked at ../src/or/connection_edge.c:2544) sending two socks replies? (on Tor 0.3.2.4-alpha )
Nov 12 18:46:19 [removed] Tor[15935]: Saying "HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed\r\n\r\n"
Nov 12 18:46:19 [removed] Tor[15935]: connection_mark_unattached_ap_(): Bug: stream (marked at ../src/or/connection_edge.c:2544) sending two socks replies? (on Tor 0.3.2.4-alpha )
Nov 12 18:49:59 [removed] Tor[15935]: Saying "HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed\r\n\r\n"
Nov 12 18:49:59 [removed] Tor[15935]: connection_mark_unattached_ap_(): Bug: stream (marked at ../src/or/connection_edge.c:2544) sending two socks replies? (on Tor 0.3.2.4-alpha )
```

This error message occurs when I try accessing plain HTTP sites using the `HTTPTunnelPort` directive. The proxy only seems to work with HTTPS sites. Is this expected behavior with the alpha release? Is it possible to access HTTP sites using the HTTPTunnelPort?

Comment: The `HTTPTunnelPort` is an HTTP CONNECT proxy, so it only accepts the CONNECT method. It seems the app is using CONNECT for HTTPS and another method for HTTP?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I'm using a mobile device. When I connect to my wifi hotspot (which is publicly hosting the tor HTTP listener, e.g. `HTTPTunnelPort 192.168.0.10:12000`), there's a setting in the wifi connection options to use a HTTP proxy. There's nothing about different methods, unfortunately. Maybe I should try Privoxy instead? What do you think?

Comment: It might be a better option, Privoxy or Polipo (Polipo is what Orbot currently uses to provide an HTTP proxy for clients on android) seem to be the choices. Polipo is probably a "lighter" option.

Answer (score 0):

i see this warn in my log, but i try and try to find problem.
my torrc config:

```
HTTPTunnelPort 0.0.0.0:8181
```

but i use different port in my apps. example, i use 8118 port in Telegram.
after change Telegram HTTP Proxy port to 8181, no longer receiving this error.